# handling SocketError ConnectionReset

Tags: c#, sockets

We have C# socketserver that was developed using `SocketAyncEventArgs` based loosely on based loosely on the MS sample: [SocketAyncEventArgs example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketasynceventargs.aspx).

Recently we had an issue with the socket server , it is not accepting new connections at all.But after restarting the service it worked.It is happenning frequently.

When I looked into the logs, I see lot of connection reset error on connecting it self.